# How do I get an access token for Microsoft Graph -- Azure docs are incorrect

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, clientcredential

I'm trying to get an access token using the OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow following [Step 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service).  Here's my curl

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d '{"grant_type":"client_credentials","client_id":"my_client_id", "client_secret":"my_client_secret", "scope":"https://graph.windows.com/.default"}' https://login.microsoftonline.com/my_tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

It gives this error message which is clearly wrong because my request body includes `grant_type`:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: a95260ff-63b6-405f-880b-738bfda33b00\r\nCorrelation ID: d606ab93-59c7-4d7d-ac45-643074e23a75\r\nTimestamp: 2023-02-24 02:29:25Z","error_codes":[900144],"timestamp":"2023-02-24 02:29:25Z","trace_id":"a95260ff-63b6-405f-880b-738bfda33b00","correlation_id":"d606ab93-59c7-4d7d-ac45-643074e23a75","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=900144"}
```

How can I get an access token to use http://graph.windows.net to find out about a registered application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added **API permissions** like below:

[image]

To run the same **curl command** via Postman, I clicked on Import and pasted code like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d '{"grant_type":"client_credentials","client_id":"678b1771-0703-401e-8056-xxxxxxxxxx", "client_secret":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "scope":"https://graph.windows.com/.default"}' https://login.microsoftonline.com/58e70374-11f2-4e91-af40-xxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

[image]

After selecting **Continue**, it took me to next screen like this:

[image]

When I clicked on `Import`, I got the screen with below parameters where I got **same error** after selecting Send like this:

[image]

> You are getting that error because you are not passing the parameters in **correct** format.

To resolve the error, try changing your **curl command** by passing parameters separated by `&` in below format:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<apID>&client_secret=<secret>&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.com%2F.default' https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

I changed the **curl command** by passing parameters in above format and imported it again like this:

[image]

When I clicked on import, parameters passed correctly in **`Body`** section but got **different error** like this:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:<appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: https://graph.windows.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the above error, I changed **`scope`** value to *https://graph.microsoft.com/.default* and got **access token** successfully like this:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:<appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

alure[image]

In your case, you need to change your **curl command** by passing parameters in correct format separated by **`&`** and **scope** value too like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<appID>&client_secret=<secret>&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Comment: The short version of your answer is that the data has to be in the form `-d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<appID>&client_secret=<secret>&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'` when the `"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` is given.